# Postgres index 2 columns with condition

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.4

Given a table of stores (~10k records) and a table of schedules(~200k records),  I am trying to create and index for the planner to use, but it ignores it so far.

```
select * from stores str
   inner join schedule sch on sch.store_id = str.store_id
where sch.open is true and sch.tables > 0

create index sch_open_tables_idx on schedule(open, tables) where open is true and tables > 0
```

Is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Could you include the log/result/test that led you to think the index is being ignored and in what query is it being ignored?

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: At least, you don't need the `open` column in the index (it will always be `true`), but `store_id` may be helpful (as the first column in that index). -- Also, you could just use `where sch.open` in both your query and index, `is true` is not necessary (but won't hurt either, nullability doesn't change things here; it just feels noise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index you need is:

```
create index sch_open_tables_id on schedule(store_id)
where open and tables > 0;
```

`store_id` is probably the primary key on the `stores` table so there is already an index on it. If not:

```
create index store_id on stores(store_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

these are 2 tables, so use 2 indices - one for each, anyway such small tables shouldn't require partial indices

```
EXPLAIN select * from stores str
   inner join schedule sch USING (store_id)
where sch.open is true and tables > 0;

create index sch_open_idx on schedule(store_id) where open is true;
create index str_tables_idx on stores(store_id) where tables > 0;

vacuum analyze stores;
vacuum analyze schedule;

EXPLAIN select * from stores str
   inner join schedule sch USING (store_id)
where sch.open is true and tables > 0;
```

Comment: Ok but why do you think the column `tables` belongs to `stores`?

Comment: Column tables belong to schedule.